# NullPointerException during datastax agent startup

Tags: opscenter

I installed DSE 4.0 and started the datastax agent and set up a 12-node cluster.
When I look in the opscenter console I see 0 nodes connected.
I see this exception in the agent log:

```
 INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-04-09 06:23:12,187 Starting up agent collection.
 INFO [Initialization] 2014-04-09 06:23:12,189 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
 INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-04-09 06:23:12,189 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
 INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-04-09 06:23:12,275 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
 INFO [Initialization] 2014-04-09 06:23:12,275 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
ERROR [Initialization] 2014-04-09 06:23:12,289 Exception in thread "Initialization"
ERROR [Initialization] 2014-04-09 06:23:12,289 java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2014-04-09 06:23:12,290 failed calling listener
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Reflector.java:296)
        at opsagent.util.cassandra_util$find_base_dse_dir.invoke(cassandra_util.clj:45)
        at opsagent.util.cassandra_util$get_base_dse_dir.invoke(cassandra_util.clj:68)
        at opsagent.util.cassandra_util$tar_conf_location.invoke(cassandra_util.clj:87)
        at opsagent.util.cassandra_util$cassandra_conf_location.invoke(cassandra_util.clj:97)
        at opsagent.util.cassandra_util$get_cassandra_conf.invoke(cassandra_util.clj:130)
        at opsagent.opsagent$create_thrift_conf_vars.invoke(opsagent.clj:52)
        at opsagent.opsagent$post_interface_startup.doInvoke(opsagent.clj:95)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at opsagent.conf$handle_new_conf.invoke(conf.clj:171)
        at opsagent.messaging$message_callback$fn__5192.invoke(messaging.clj:30)
        at opsagent.messaging.proxy$java.lang.Object$StompConnection$Listener$7f16bc72.onMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.jgroups.client.StompConnection.notifyListeners(StompConnection.java:311)
        at org.jgroups.client.StompConnection.run(StompConnection.java:261)
```

I tried changing the log level to ALL but it didn't add log messages to this snippet.

Comment: This is not the place to submit bug reports.

Comment: OpsCenter 4.1.2 was released a few hours ago and should fix this.  If it doesn't, try adding `cassandra_conf: /path/to/cassandra.yaml` in the agent's address.yaml and restart